# Hide US on google geochart when region is set to Canada

Tags: region, regions, google-visualization

I need to hide US on geo chart, when region is set to Canada:

google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

```
 data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Value'); 
 data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'});var ivalue = new Array();

 data.addRows([[{v:'CA-BC',f:'CA-BC'},0,'Test']]);

 var options = {
 backgroundColor: {fill:'#FFFFFF',stroke:'#FFFFFF' ,strokeWidth:0 },
 colorAxis:  {minValue: 0, maxValue: 0,  colors: ['#0000ff',]},
 legend: 'none',    
 backgroundColor: {fill:'#FFFFFF',stroke:'#FFFFFF' ,strokeWidth:0 },    
 datalessRegionColor: '#f5f5f5',
 displayMode: 'markers', 
 enableRegionInteractivity: 'true', 
 resolution: 'provinces',
 region:'CA',
 keepAspectRatio: true,
 width:700,
 height:500,
 tooltip: {textStyle: {color: '#444444'}, trigger:'focus'}    
 };
  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization')); 
 chart.draw(data, options);
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jk171505/VJtBR/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the API options, you can't really do it. 
You can use advanced CSS selectors to hide the SVG shapes.

Add this CSS and it will hide the US shapes:

```
#visualization path:nth-child(237), #visualization path:nth-child(236) {
    display:none;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cmoreira/mMadX

I have built a page with some information on how to use this and other CSS techniques with the Google Geochart API. In case it helps, here's the link: http://cmoreira.net/interactive-world-maps-demo/advanced-customization/

Comment: I did something similar, but using jquery.